# pycharm input returns an int instead of string?

Tags: python, pycharm, python-2.x

I am new to python programming. I am using latest version of pyCharm and doing remote debugging of some code which is on raspberrypi. There is this code.

```
# Get the verifier code from the user. Do this however you
# want, as long as the user gives the application the code.
verifier = input('Verifier code: ')
```

Where I enter some string like 117-820-181 on the console window and in the veriifer variable it shows up as an int. on the next line the code breaks as it expects verifier to be string and not int.
Any ideas why this is returning int instead of string ?

Comment: Do you use Python 2.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you are using Python 2.x (`input` in that version evaluates the given input as code, which is what seems to be happening. Also, I think that PyCharm likes to use Python 2.x rather than 3.x).

If this is so, then use `raw_input()` (which returns everything as a `str`ing, much like Python 3.x’s `input()` function does):

```
verifier = raw_input('Verifier code: ')
```

This will stop the issue where the verification code is turned into an `int`eger.

Comment: You are right, my remote interpretter was python 2.7 which caused the issue. changing it to python 3 resolved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Make it a string on input

```
    verifier = str(input('Verifier code: '))
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, if there are only numbers in an input, python automatically assumes that its an integer

Comment: I do not want it to assume that, essentially those are dashes in between I guess python thinks it is a negative number ??

Comment: I know you don't want it to assume that, so do what I said to do in my answer :D

Comment: That does not solve my problem, the return value of input function changes the input entirely.. changing its type alone won't help

Comment: Why-ever not? Did you try it?